# How to avoid inserting duplicate values in a HashMap?

Tags: hashmap, duplicates

Let say we have :
Map hm = new HashMap();

How to avoid putting duplicate values(Emplyees) in this HashMap?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are coding in Java, so:

```
if(!myMap.containsKey(myKey)){
    myMap.put(myKey, myValue);
}
```

The good thing with `HashMap` is that the `containsKey` method takes constant time (or constant amortized time) regardless of the number of elements in your map so you can call it without bothering of the time it may take!

If you use an other language, the logic remains the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am using java, I knew about these two functions, I don't know why someone told me to implement equal and hashcode in employee and I got confused.

Comment: When you add objects to a HashMap, it is good practice to override their hashCode and equals methods: https://dev.youdevise.com/YDBlog/index.php/2008/04/15/equals_and_hashcode_in_java

Comment: why override their hashCode and equals methods if we have containKey and containValue methods ?

Comment: When you put an object into a map, it is added at some place according to its hash (the result of the hashCode method). When you call containsKey(key), the hash of the key is computed and the object in your map that has been placed at the place corresponding to this key is retrieved and if it is not null (meaning that an object having the same hash has already been inserted) then true is returned if your key and this retrieved object are equal in terms of == (same object in memory) OR if the key.equals(retrievedObject) returns true. Therefore you may want to implement those two methods!

Comment: Thank you very much Vakimshaar, I appreciate your help and time. It is possible to put a small example please ?

Answer (score 1):

I think duplicate values in Map can be removed using this generic method if your userdefined object is overridden with equals and hashcode from object class

```
public static <K, V > Map<K,V> genericMethodtoDeleteMapduplicate(Map<K, V> pMap) {
    Map<K,V> mapWithoutDup=new HashMap<>();

    Set<V> totalvaluesPresent=new HashSet<>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> a : pMap.entrySet()) {
        if(totalvaluesPresent.add(a.getValue())){
        mapWithoutDup.put(a.getKey(), a.getValue());
        }
    }
    return mapWithoutDup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are using but in java for Hashmap their are:

> boolean   containsKey(Object key) 
>             - Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the
>   specified key.

and

> boolean   containsValue(Object value) 
>             - Returns true if this map maps one or more keys to the
>   specified value.

Just call which ever one makes more sense for you to check if the entry is already in the map, if it is then you know its a duplicate, otherwise put it in.  I'm certain whatever language you are using will have something similar!!